# Why does this program print 23 after casting?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
uint32_t x;
uint32_t* p = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
uint32_t array[9] = {42, 5, 23, 82, 127, 21, 324, 3, 8};
*p = *(uint32_t*) ((char*) array + 8);
printf("l: %d\n", *p);

return 0;

}
```

Why does `*p` print the value of the second index of `array` after `*p = *(uint32_t*) ((char*) array + 8);` ?

Comment: What do you expect it to print? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(uint32_t)` is `4`

`sizeof(char)` is `1` => `8 * sizeof(char) == 8`

`8 / sizeof(uint32_t) = 2`

then `((char *)array) + 8 == array + (8 / sizeof(uint32_t))`

`p = array + (8 / sizeof(uint32_t))`  => `p = array + 2`

then `*p == array[2] == 23`

Comment: Why are you doing ```8 / sizeof(uint32_t)``` ? 
Is this because of the ```uint32_t*``` cast ?

Comment: because `p` & `array` are  `uint32_t *` and we reading it as `uint32_t`

Comment: @AdrianMole wring!!! it makes a difference because of initialization. If the `array` was for example `uint64_t` or `uint16_t` the result would not be `23`.

Comment: OK - I expressed myself badly. The size of the pointed-to object of the second (outer) cast makes no difference - you've added 8 bytes to the array's address, so the subsequent dereference will not be influenced by the cast.

Comment: @AdrianMole where did I write that it will be? I do not understand the reason for the comment.

Comment: First two comments.

Comment: @AdrianMole I explain why this `+8` becomes `+2` and it is strictly related to type of `p`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the question revolves around operator precedence and associativity.  This expression ...

> ```
> *(uint32_t*) ((char*) array + 8)
> ```

... is equivalent to ...

```
*((uint32_t*) (((char*) array) + 8))
```

... NOT ...

```
*((uint32_t*) ((char*) (array + 8)))  // not equivalent
```

Typecast operators have very high precedence, higher than binary `+`, in particular.  Pointer arithmetic works in units of the pointed-to type, and the type of `((char *) array)` is, or course, `char *`.  Its pointed to type is `char`.  Therefore, `(((char*) array) + 8)` evaluates to a pointer to the 8<sup>th</sup> *char* past the beginning of the array.

Your implementation has 8-bit `char`s, which is exceedingly common (but not universal).  Type `uint32_t` has exactly 32 bits, and so comprises four 8-bit `char`s.  It follows that `(((char*) array) + 8)` points to the first `char` of the third `uint32_t` in `array`, as the 8 bytes skipped are exactly the bytes of the first two `uint32_t`s.

When that pointer is converted back to type `uint32_t *`, it points to the whole third `uint32_t` of the array, and the value of that element, 23, is read back by dereferencing the pointer with the unary `*` operator.